listings - beauty table from emacs with iteral command
I would like to beauty a table output from emacs, the + looks weird. any suggestion to improve it?
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{terminal} {
  literate=
    {|}{{\smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}}}1
    {-}{{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{1.5ex}{1pt}}}}1
    {+}{{
        \smash{
          \raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2ex}{1pt}}          
          \raisebox{-1ex}{\rule{1pt}{4ex}}
          \raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2ex}{1pt}}
        }
    }}1
    ,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{white},
  showstringspaces=false,
}
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\pagecolor[RGB]{0,0,0}% 
\begin{lstlisting}[
    style=terminal,
  ]
+--------+---------+
| name   |   value |
|--------+---------|
| A      |       1 |
| B      |       2 |
+--------+---------+
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


Output:


since this is a code listing, it presumably needs to be verbatim i.e. I assume this is the output from a command or programme which you need to include. that being the case, it isn't clear what you want it to look like instead. why does the style imitate + with rules rather than just using a +, for example? I mean, why are you using this style in the first place?
